# Using d3.js in Angular2

Tags: javascript, angular, d3.js

There are a few question on SO about it, but unfortunately they all seem to be deprecated.

Im using angular2 with angular-cli.

To install d3.js im using `npm install d3`.

My `app.component.ts` file:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import * as d3 from 'd3';

@Component({
  selector: 'app',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.css']
})

export class AppComponent {
}
```

But somehow, the app doesnt load correctly because of error: 
`Cannot find module 'd3'.`

That's kinda strange, especially because the Webstorm is able to see the file and doesn't report any problems.

I also tried to install the **c3.js** library and after installing ive tried the same import way:

`npm install c3`

and

`import * as c3 from 'c3';`

But it doesnt work aswell as the first one.

**EDIT!**

After using commands:

`npm install d3 --save`

`npm install @types/d3 --save-dev`

like @Tudor Ciotlos mentioned, Im getting few errors.

> [default] C:\Users\node_modules\@types\c3\index.d.ts:28:41
>       Generic type 'Selection' requires 4 type argument(s).
>   [default] C:\Users\node_modules\@types\c3\index.d.ts:351:56
>
> Module '" C:\Users\node_modules/@types/d3/index"' has no
>   exported member 'Rgb'.
>   [default] C:\Users\node_modules\@types\c3\index.d.ts:355:47
>
> Module '"C:/Users/node_modules/@types/d3/index"' has no
>   exported member 'Rgb'.
>   [default] C:\Users\ode_modules\@types\c3\index.d.ts:833:51
>
> Module '"C:/Users/node_modules/@types/d3/index"' has no
>   exported member 'Rgb'.
>   [default] C:\Users\node_modules\@types\c3\index.d.ts:943:58
>
> Module '"C:/Users/node_modules/@types/d3/index"' has no
>   exported member 'Rgb'.

Anyone knows why Im getting these errors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to installing the d3 package, you will also have to install the associated typings:

```
npm install d3 --save
npm install @types/d3 --save-dev
```

You can find more information about [3rd Party Library Installation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#3rd-party-library-installation) and [Global Library Installation](https://github.com/angular/angular-cli#global-library-installation) in the angular-cli readme on GitHub.

Comment: @H.Doe I just tried these steps on a freshly installed angular2 app using angular-cli and it works, I get no errors like yours. Could you maybe try to do a fresh install of your application?

Comment: Yeah. It works. Thank u. But the errors still appears. But they dont affect the app.

Answer (score 1):

This was happening to me as well - I am using angular-cli and d3 v4 and only getting errors in development.

In addition to `import * as d3 from "d3";` add the code below to your typings.d.ts file:

```
declare module 'd3' {
  export * from 'd3-array';
  export * from 'd3-axis';
  export * from 'd3-brush';
  export * from 'd3-chord';
  export * from 'd3-collection';
  export * from 'd3-color';
  export * from 'd3-dispatch';
  export * from 'd3-drag';
  export * from 'd3-dsv';
  export * from 'd3-ease';
  export * from 'd3-force';
  export * from 'd3-format';
  export * from 'd3-geo';
  export * from 'd3-hierarchy';
  export * from 'd3-interpolate';
  export * from 'd3-path';
  export * from 'd3-polygon';
  export * from 'd3-quadtree';
  export * from 'd3-queue';
  export * from 'd3-random';
  export * from 'd3-request';
  export * from 'd3-scale';
  export * from 'd3-selection';
  export * from 'd3-shape';
  export * from 'd3-time';
  export * from 'd3-time-format';
  export * from 'd3-timer';
  export * from 'd3-transition';
  export * from 'd3-voronoi';
  export * from 'd3-zoom';
}
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Another path to explore is to use a ng library wrapping D3 functionality.
For example, **[d3-ng2-service](https://github.com/tomwanzek/d3-ng2-service)** wraps D3 v.4 for consumption in Angular providing TS typings at the same time.